# Performance - Huge string constants is duplicated across multiple class files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, sonarqube

I am getting sonar vilation Performance - Huge string constants is duplicated across multiple class files.

What is the reason i am getting this?
How to resolve this?

This is the code

```
public static final String GET_CO_ADMIN_GRID_DTLS ="A 30 line huge query";
```

Comment: without seeing your code, don't know, I do know, however, that sonar always shows an example of what it is complaining about in your code. check that example and use it as a reference.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution :** Performance - Huge string constants is duplicated across multiple class files.

1.Declare the class as final , make the field as public static final and assign inside static block.
2.Dont Forget to declare private constructor otherwise sonar will show "utility classes should not be public or default constructor as (MAJOR issue)".

```
public final class QueryConstants {
/**
 * Default Constructor.
 */
private QueryConstants(){
    //
}
public static final String COMMON_SELECT;
static {
    COMMON_SELECT = "Your Query Here";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because of final keyword. the final field coppied into reference class also.

A large String constant is duplicated across multiple class files. This is likely because a final field is initialized to a String constant, and the Java language mandates that all references to a final field from other classes be inlined into that classfile. See JDK bug 6447475 for a description of an occurrence of this bug in the JDK and how resolving it reduced the size of the JDK by 1 megabyte.

We need to remove final keyword from that string....

Comment: Removing the `final` keyword is probably not an acceptable solution, as it makes your 'constant' mutable. See @Ankit's answer, about sharing this `String` between classes instead of duplicating it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Gowtham is the right one. Creating a Constants class doesn't solve the problem

```
// creating the constants class like this would lead into duplication of the huge string assigned to FOO
// class A and B would also contain the huge string, after compilation
class C {
    public static final String FOO = "HUGE STRING";
}

class A {
    public void f() {
        String c = C.FOO;
    }
}

class B {
    public void f() {
        String c = C.FOO;
    }
}
```

creating the constant class like proposed in the mentioned bug report http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6447475 avoid the duplication of the huge string

```
class C {
    public static final String FOO;
    static {
        FOO = "BAR";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string constant is same, then create a Constants file and place that constant there. Use that constant in your multiple class files. like:

```
Constants.CONSTANT_1
```